# Javascript regex matching at least one letter or number?

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the JavaScript regex to match a string with at least one letter or number? This should require at least one alphanumeric character (at least one letter OR at least one number).

Comment: I see you've already gotten some answers, but did you try anything before coming to SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a pattern matching any string that contains an alphanumeric char is

```
.*[A-Za-z0-9].*
^.*[A-Za-z0-9].*
^[^A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9][\w\W]*
```

However, a regex requirement like this is usually set up with a look-ahead at the beginning of a pattern.

Here is one that meets your criteria:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

And then goes the rest of your regex. Say, and min 7 characters, then add: `.{7,}$`.

```js
var re = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]).{7,}$/; 
var str = '1234567';
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = m[0];
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: Why so complex? You could simply test for `/[a-z0-9]/`, or even `/\w/` ...?

Comment: If the condition is part of 1 regex, then it is OK, and is by no way complex. If you can use 2 steps during validation, I would definitely use `/[a-z0-9]/i`. Not `\w` as it also allows an underscore.

Answer (score -1):

something like this? `/^.*[\d\w]+.*$/`

Comment: If you're going to match every character after the start and end anchors, you might as well leave them out: `/[\d\w]/`. Also `\d` is part of `\w`, so you don't need that. And finally, if you're leaving with just /[\w]/, you can omit the character class, because now you have only one character left: `/\w/` :)